# ppo_trainer generate and training step is extremely slow

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, large-language-model

I am running the code exactly as shown in this Github repo: https://github.com/joeljang/RLPHF/blob/main/training/rlhf.py

For some reason, this code block:

```
for steps, batch in tqdm(enumerate(ppo_trainer.dataloader)):
    question_tensors = batch["input_ids"]
    response_tensors = ppo_trainer.generate(
        question_tensors,
        return_prompt=False,
        length_sampler=output_length_sampler,
        **generation_kwargs,
    )
    batch["response"] = tokenizer.batch_decode(response_tensors, skip_special_tokens=True)

    texts = [q + r for q, r in zip(batch["query"], batch["response"])]
    input_ids = tokenizer(texts, max_length=script_args.max_length ,return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True).input_ids
    reward_outputs = reward_model(input_ids = input_ids.to(reward_model.device))[0]
    rewards = [torch.tensor(output[0].float()) - script_args.reward_baseline for output in reward_outputs]
    v_min, v_max, v_mean = get_reward_stats(rewards)
    # Run PPO step
    stats = ppo_trainer.step(question_tensors, response_tensors, rewards)
```

Is taking an extremely long time, even though it's primarily just (1) generate, (2) obtain reward, and (3) backpropagate. I am using a single A100 80GB GPU and it is taking about ~15 minutes for a SINGLE training step. Is that how long it should take? I also checked that the model, question_tensors, response_tensors, and rewards are all on the gpu by using .device. I noticed that question_tensors is a list of tensors, rather than a tensor of tensors. But ppo_trainer.generate does not take in a tensor of tensors as an input datatype. This is with the Llama 7B model.

Why is it taking so long?